# In TypeScript, define a type for any object that has required properties

Tags: typescript

Say I have a function that takes some sort of object that has a `name` property. It doesn't care about the other properties on the object, only that it has a `name` of type `string`, thus it should accept any object type that conforms to this.

Is there a simple way to define such a type? The closest I've got is to extend a type constructed with `Record` but it seems a bit inelegant:

```
interface ThingWithName extends Record<string, any> {
    name: string
}

function greet(thing: ThingWithName) {
    return `hello, ${thing.name}`
}

greet({name: ''}) // fine
greet({name: '', age: 27}) // also fine
```

Comment: `interface ThingWithName { name: string; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special for this. This will define the required property:

```
interface ThingWithName {
    name: string
}

function greet(thing: ThingWithName) {
    return `hello, ${thing.name}`
}

greet({name: ''}) // fine
let x = {name: '', age: 27};
greet(x) // also fine
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoAtQHMDqwzoBycAtigN4BQyNyIpEAXMgM5hTaUC+llMAriARhgAexDIsUCBDAAKAtmYZseAsTIBKZFVrJpYflAkADdBAA2F0QBpkAEnKKQWAHT0yXE915SZ88g8mZAByEK5tAHpI5BhQCEoLWWQAD2QAXh0g5jC7OCxggCYAdi4Abko-WTkUqJi4CxZRWPigA)

What you are probably hitting up against is excess property checks that prohibit extra properties when an object literal is directly assigned to a specific type reference. So in  the code above this: `greet({name: '', age: 27})` would be an error.

You can get around this limitation in one of several ways.

The safest one is to use a generic type parameter:

```
interface ThingWithName {
    name: string
}

function greet<T extends ThingWithName>(thing: T) {
    return `hello, ${thing.name} ${thing.age}` // age is invalid
}

greet({name: ''}) // fine
greet({name: '', age: 27}) // also fine
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoAtQHMDqwzoBycAtigN4BQyNyIpEAXMgM5hTaUC+llMAriARhgAexDIsUCBDAAeVMggAPSCAAmLNJhC58RBgD4AFAWzNUASmRVayaWH5QJAA3QQANh9EAaZABJyM10AOnoyLgCgnSwQuCwILhdkAHoU5HiUYC1QADc4D2B1bl4pGTBjcnCmZAByWq5rNOQYUAhKMtlK6uZ6v0zmACYAdkbU9IKWURa2oA)

If you want to be able to index into the object using a `string` then the solution you found of extending record is an ok one (same effect could have been achieved using an index signature):

```
interface ThingWithName extends Record<string, any> {
    name: string
}

function greet(thing: ThingWithName) {
    return `hello, ${thing.name} ${thing.age}` // age is valid, so be ware you can dot into thing with any prop 
}

greet({name: ''}) // fine
greet({ }) // err
greet({name: '', age: 27}) // also fine
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoAtQHMDqwzoBycAtihAB6QgAmAzsgEoQID2UNAPHWFNgDTI4IAJ4A+ZAG8AUMjnIQpCAC5kPPiCzSAvtOkwAriARhgrEMixQIEMAAoC2VRmx4CxMgEops+dbAGUBYABugQADbhrIIAJJKOmgB0imTayHEJWIlwWBDawcgA9IVCucjADABucOHANIJ0rMgARigA7nDWyCKsBsgIwsg0rGDl4E2ZyG346EKiyAAOUKwLyDp6Vjb2kikqyADk+9rexcgwoBDSm7Z2ksjHRSXQUFfWNztKqoeCOXsATAB2B6nGqNM4XIA)

Comment: Was the exact match against literals added recently? I think just some time ago it would have been valid

Comment: @zerkms excess property checks have been around a long time (since before 2.0 for sure). They mostly works as you expect them to, but in like 20% of cases they surprise you 

Comment: Awesome, I knew there was something I was missing there.